# Interpreting logistic regression output in R to get odds ratios for categorical variables

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm trying to run a series of univariate logistic regressions with categorical predictor variables, but my basic stats have gotten rusty and I've run into some confusion. I'm aware that many other users have asked similar questions, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer that I can directly apply to my example, and different functions have been giving me different estimates.

Here is an example dataframe (can't share my actual data):

```
#Creating sample dataframe
df<- structure(list(
'sick'=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),
'agecat'=c(23,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,4,4,1,3,1,2,4), 'gender'=c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)))
#Factoring vars
df$agecat <- factor(df$agecat, levels=c(1,2,3,4), labels=c("0-19","20-39","40-59","60-79"))
df$gender <- factor(df$gender, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("male","female"))
```

This is the code I'm using to run a series of univariate logistic regressions:

```
#Identifying predictor columns
predictors <- c('agecat', 'gender')
cols <- df[predictors]

#Using lapply to generate list of unadjusted logistic regression output
A <- lapply(as.list(cols), function(x) glm(sick ~ x, data=df, family=binomial(link="logit")))
A
```

I have confirmed that this works by creating individual models for gender and agecat and comparing those results to the numbers in A, eg:

```
m <- glm(sick ~ gender, data=df, family=binomial(link="logit"))
m
```

My understanding is that the estimates produced in A are the log odds, and must be exponentiated to get the odds ratios. Below is the code I'm using to do that:

```
#Creating tibble from list and exponentiating 
do.call(rbind, lapply(A, broom::tidy, exponentiate=TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)) -> B
B
```

I believe this is working as expected, since the new estimates in B match the numbers I get when I run `exp(coef(m))` on the results of my individual models for gender and agecat.

**My main questions:** How should I be interpreting the estimates produced in B? Am I correct that they are odds ratios? If so, why are the estimates for intercepts/reference groups not 1.00?

If the results in B are odds ratios that have been correctly calculated, should I or should I not include those intercepts when displaying the results in a table or plot? I know generally intercepts aren't displayed, but the fact that they're not 1.00 is throwing me off.

I'm concerned because when I try to calculate the odds ratio directly using epitools as a check, I get slightly different numbers. However, other methods to calculate odds ratios do match my results in B (e.g. odds.ratio from the questionr package) - am I just using the epitools function incorrectly, or have I made some other mistake?

```
epitools::oddsratio(x=df$gender, y=df$sick) #produces OR of 0.47 for female instead of expected 0.44

questionr::odds.ratio(m) #produces expected 0.44 OR for female
```

Comment: You may get different results even if using the same package. Try `epitools::oddsratio(x=dd$gender, y=dd$sick, method = "wald")`

Comment: Thank you! Running it in epitools with "wald" gives me a matching OR for female, although the CI numbers are still slightly different from the results in B. Also, why are the exponentiated intercept estimates in B not 1.00?